# Cache expensive JBuilder result from frequent resquest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, jbuilder

I've and endpoint that generates a Json response using JBuilder.
However, this Json is very slow to craft and since this request is made every few seconds and it don't need to be updated everytime, I decided to cache it.

It's a complicated-ish Json with nested attributes and it access some model associations.

How can I cache the json result and just render it to the user every x minutes?

file.json.jbuilder:

```
json.array!(@photos) do |photo|
  json.extract! photo, :id, :title, :description, :image_updated_at
  json.camera_roll_image_url URI.join(request.url, photo.image.url(:camera_roll)).to_s
  json.original_image_url URI.join(request.url, photo.image.url).to_s
  json.has_picture true

  json.girl do 
    json.extract! photo.girl, :id, :name, :phone, :ddd, :country_code, :approved, :gender, :likes, :is_ad, :ad_type
    json.user_liked photo.girl.liked_by_user?(@user)
    if(photo.girl.is_ad == 1)
      json.ad_info do
        json.extract! photo.girl, :price, :description, :address, :ad_type
      end
    end
    json.is_featured photo.girl.is_featured? 
    json.avatar URI.join(request.url, photo.girl.avatar.url(:thumb)).to_s
    json.age photo.girl.age
    json.country_num_code photo.girl.country_num_code
    json.type photo.girl.type
  end

  json.check_in do
    json.extract! photo.girl.check_ins.last, :latitude, :longitude
  end

  json.userLat @userLat
  json.userLong @userLong

  json.likes photo.likes
  json.user_liked photo.liked_by_user? @current_user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

well, there are several caching mechanisms integrated into rails. you can read about them in the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

in your specific case, there are several options, all of them have a high chance of success.

before caching anything, i would want to find out which part is most expensive and then cache that one and see if it is good enough.

if your clients are smart, you could also make use of etags, but all of this depends very much on your usecase (as always when it comes to caching).

side note, if you have something like nginx, you can use it as a reverse proxy https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/